# Read xml file properties from URL

Tags: java, xml, url

I'm trying to read some properties from a file which I have in a URL and when I do it, I have these properties to null and I don't know why. This is my code:

```
Properties propiedades = new Properties(); 

URL url2= new URL("http://localhost:3624/web/applets/paqProperties/configuration.xml");
InputStream in =url2.openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
propiedades.load(reader);
//propiedades.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream("paqProperties/configuration.xml"));
//propiedades.load(new FileInputStream("paqProperties/configuracion.properties"));

soapAction=propiedades.getProperty("soapAction");
servidor=propiedades.getProperty("servidor");
url=propiedades.getProperty("urlWS");
```

Why happen this? I just have the last line and this is the output of the xml:

```
   <properties>
    <entry key="soapAction">http://localhost:3624/</entry>
    <entry key="servidor">http://localhost:3624/web/soa/</entry>
    <entry key="urlWS">http://localhost:3624/web/soa/soa.asmx</entry>
    <entry key="servidor2">http://localhost:3624/web/soa/</entry>
    <entry key="soapAction2">http://localhost:3624/web/soa/getURL</entry>
   </properties>
```

Comment: What is `propiedades`?

Comment: What happens if you access your URL through `curl`or a web browser? Do you get the xml file?

Comment: Yes I get it.So I don't know

Comment: Can you show the content of the xml file?

Comment: Try:
1) `propiedades.loadFromXML(in);` instead of 2 "`reader`" lines.
2) to iterate through `p.keySet()` and print all keys

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpURLConnection` to get your `InputStream`.

```
String uri = YOUR_URL
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();

...

connection.disconnect();
```